# How to use hex function with abi.encodeWithSignature()

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

Solidity version used: 0.4.24

Can this:

```
    if(!addr.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("SomeFunction(uint256,uint256)",100,22))){
        revert();
    }
```

Be converted to this :

```
    if(!addr.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("0xdchbe039000000000000002"))){
        revert();
    }
```

hex ?

Comment: you can call it directly 'if(!addr.call("0xdchbe039000000000000002"))'

Comment: does not work ,i tried that.

Comment: It's working fine for me, calling the function using hexcode, Could you provide the sample function to replicate the problem